# Splitting one Results Set into multiples based on column for XML formatting

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to split an SQL results set (in a Stored Proc) into multiple columns for XML formatting. I have a results set with a Supplier Number and a Product Number like this:

```
SupplierID    ProdCode
-----------   --------- 
Supp1         Prod1
Supp1         Prod2
Supp1         Prod3
Supp2         Prod2
Supp2         Prod3
Supp3         Prod2
```

etc.

I need to split this results set so that each supplier has its own dataset, which can then be split into its own XML node, as shown here:

```xml
<SUPPLIER>
    <SUPPLIER_LINES>
        <SUPPNO>Supp1</SUPPNO>
        <PRODCODE>Prod1</WWPROD>
    </SUPPLIER_LINES>
    <SUPPLIER_LINES>
        <SUPPNO>Supp1</SUPPNO>
        <PRODCODE>Prod2</WWPROD>
    </SUPPLIER_LINES>
    <SUPPLIER_LINES>
        <SUPPNO>Supp1</SUPPNO>
        <PRODCODE>Prod3</WWPROD>
    </SUPPLIER_LINES>
</SUPPLIER>
<SUPPLIER>
    <SUPPLIER_LINES>
        <SUPPNO>Supp2</SUPPNO>
        <PRODCODE>Prod2</WWPROD>
    </SUPPLIER_LINES>
    <SUPPLIER_LINES>
        <SUPPNO>Supp2</SUPPNO>
        <PRODCODE>Prod3</WWPROD>
    </SUPPLIER_LINES>
</SUPPLIER>
```

I'll be able to figure out the XML formatting, but am having trouble splitting the results inside a stored proc to get this:

```
SupplierID  ProdCode
Supp1       Prod1
Supp1       Prod2

SupplierID  ProdCode
Supp2       Prod2
Supp2       Prod3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a `group by` on `SupplierID` for the `SUPPLIER` nodes and use a correlated sub-query to get the `SUPPLIER_LINES` nodes.

```
select (
         select T2.SupplierID as SUPNO,
                T2.ProdCode as PRODCODE
         from YourTable as T2
         where T1.SupplierID = T2.SupplierID  
         for xml path('SUPPLIER_LINES'), type
       )
from YourTable as T1
group by SupplierID
for xml path('SUPPLIER')
```

You probably have suppliers in table of it's own so if you use that table in the main query you don't have to do the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to generate separate result sets in your SP (which I think is what you're asking).

By various tweaking of the `FOR XML` options, you should be able to generate this XML in one query, although you may need to use the `EXPLICIT` option.

This should be a good starting point

```
select 
    SupplierID as SuppNo,
    ProdCode
from 
    #t
for xml path('Supplier'), elements, type
```